# Rust: Use of Mutable References in Recursive Function

Tags: recursion, rust, borrow-checker

Am trying to print unique contiguous sub-arrays of a `Vec` using a recursive function like so:

```rust
use std::collections::HashSet;

fn recurse<'a>(nums: &'a [i32], already_printed: &'a mut HashSet<&'a [i32]>) {
    if !already_printed.contains(nums) {
        println!("{:#?}", nums);
    }

    already_printed.insert(nums);

    if nums.len() >= 2 {
        recurse(&nums[0..nums.len() - 1], already_printed);
        recurse(&nums[1..nums.len()], already_printed);
    }
}

pub fn main() {
    let k = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
    let mut already_printed: HashSet<&[i32]> = HashSet::new();
    recurse(&k[0..], &mut already_printed);
}
```

This of course, as experienced Rustaceans may have guessed already, fails to compile with the following error:

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `*already_printed` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src/main.rs:12:39
   |
3  | fn recurse<'a>(nums: &'a [i32], already_printed: &'a mut HashSet<&'a [i32]>) {
   |            -- lifetime `'a` defined here
...
11 |         recurse(&nums[0..nums.len() - 1], already_printed);
   |         --------------------------------------------------
   |         |                                 |
   |         |                                 first mutable borrow occurs here
   |         argument requires that `*already_printed` is borrowed for `'a`
12 |         recurse(&nums[1..nums.len()], already_printed);
   |                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ second mutable borrow occurs here

error: aborting due to previous error

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0499`.
```

I understand from the very helpful error *why* the compiler refuses to compile this. However, what would be a workaround, generally speaking, to implement recursive functions that take mutable references as shown in the above code?

A possible workaround method I could think of was using the *interior mutability pattern* à la `RefCell`:

```
use std::cell::RefCell;
use std::collections::HashSet;

fn recurse<'a>(nums: &'a [i32], already_printed: &'a RefCell<HashSet<&'a [i32]>>) {
    if !already_printed.borrow().contains(nums) {
        println!("{:#?}", nums);
    }

    already_printed.borrow_mut().insert(nums);

    if nums.len() >= 2 {
        recurse(&nums[0..nums.len() - 1], already_printed);
        recurse(&nums[1..nums.len()], already_printed);
    }
}

pub fn main() {
    let k = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
    let already_printed: HashSet<&[i32]> = HashSet::new();
    let ref_cell: RefCell<HashSet<&[i32]>> = RefCell::new(already_printed);
    recurse(&k[0..], &ref_cell);
}
```

While this works, this seems to be discarding the safety rails that the compile time borrow checker provides. Is there a different canonical way to make recursive function calls like the above while still having compile time borrow checker pass?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The magical solution is to change the declaration of the function to

```
fn recurse<'a, 'b>(nums: &'a [i32], already_printed: &'b mut HashSet<&'a [i32]>) {
// I just changed this lifetime -----------------------^
```

There was no deep reason for your algorithm not to work, except that you added too many constraints when there was no reason.

When you call `recurse` from inside `recurse`, it's totally fine, as it frees ownership on end of call. So it must work.

But you required that all lifetimes be the same while you could just let the compiler determine the real constraints.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply.